# Autofac - constructor on type 'X' not found

Tags: c#, reflection, autofac

I have a problem when trying to inject one dependency into the one I'm currently registering.  I have an application that upon starting inits a bootstrap loader to read from a settings file, and then creates an object using reflection from a particular value in this settings file.  I'll try and let the code do the talking here.

**Settings file**

The settings file is a plain old XML file, that serializes / deserializes to an object called `BootstrapSettings` which adheres to the following contract:

```
public interface IBootstrapSettings
{
    string Get(string key);
    void Set(string key, string value);
}
```

Within this settings file, I have a particular key that identifies what `IEncryptor` I intend to use for this application, at the moment I have a choice of `PlainTextEncryptor` or `TDESEncryptor`, the latter reads a passphrase from  the settings file and so in its constructor I am passing an instance of `IBootstrapSettings` to read this passphrase from the settings file. At the moment I am injecting an instance of `IBootstrapSettings` into each encryptor - even though `PlainTextEncryptor` doesn't use it.  I'm doing this because I'm having to create this instance using reflection and don't know how I can differentiate between a constructor that doesn't take a parameter and a constructor that does when creating an `IEncryptor` type (but this is another question I suppose).

**IEncryptor constructors**

The following are the constructors for each `IEncryptor` I currently have.

```
public sealed class PlainTextEncryptor : IEncryptor
{
    private readonly IBootstrapSettings _bootstrapSettings;

    public PlainTextEncryptor(IBootstrapSettings bootstrapSettings)
    {
        _bootstrapSettings = bootstrapSettings;
    }
}

public sealed class TDESEncryptor : IEncryptor
{
    private readonly IBootstrapSettings _bootstrapSettings;

    public TDESEncryptor(IBootstrapSettings bootstrapSettings)
    {
        _bootstrapSettings = bootstrapSettings;
    }
}
```

**Injection**

Onto how I'm setting up my dependencies.  I have an Autofac module that creates the bootstrap dependencies before anything else is created - it looks like this:

```
public sealed class BootstrapSettingsModule : Autofac.Module
{
    private readonly string _filePath;

    public BootstrapSettingsModule(string filePath)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);

        builder.Register(c => new BootstrapSettings(_bootstrapSettingsPath))
            .As<IBootstrapSettings>()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => (IEncryptor)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(c.Resolve<IBootstrapSettings>().Get("encryptionprovider")), args: new { bootstrapSettings = c.Resolve<IBootstrapSettings>() }))
            .As<IEncryptor>()
            .SingleInstance();
    }
}
```

Now this executes fine, the problem occurs when I try to `.Resolve` an instance of `IEncryptor` I am getting the error **Constructor on type 'whatever encryptor type' not found**. I assume this is because Autofac cannot resolve my `IBootstrapSettings` and because I have no default parameterless constructor on my `IEncryptor` it's throwing a fit.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to what to do here, am I doing something wrong by specifying the `IBootstrapSettings` as a single instance... or do I just not understand Autofac's binding correctly?  Appreciate any help as always!

Comment: Please show the constructors of the encryptor classes.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth updated with constructor code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you are not just using the facilities of Autofac.

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    base.Load(builder);

    var settings = new BootstrapSettings(_bootstrapSettingsPath);
    builder.RegisterInstance(settings)
        .As<IBootstrapSettings>()
        .SingleInstance();

    var encryptorType = Type.GetType(settings.Get("encryptionprovider"));
    builder.RegisterType(encryptorType)
        .As<IEncryptor>()
        .SingleInstance();
}
```

This would give you the additional advantage that you wouldn't need to have a constructor with an `IBootstrapSettings` parameter in every encryptor. You would need it just in those that really make use of that parameter.

Comment: Excellent!! I'm a newbie to Autofac and wasn't aware I could use `RegisterType` instead of reflection to do what I wanted. This works perfectly thanks a lot! It says I can accept as answer in 3 mins so will do.